# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length in weighting

Tags: r, regression

I am using multinomial regression to get the probability of  belonging to four sub-groups for 500,000 regions. 
The data.frame looks like this:

```
Regions        groupadmit        mid-pop
1                 2               1764
2                 3               1254
25                1               1452
674               4               2665
3001              2               1097
56                3               9864
98                1               2675
500,000          ....             .....
```

I wrote the following code:

```
library (nnet)
mlogit<- multinom(groupadmit~mid_pop, data = admissionLSOA1)
probs <- predict(mlogit, type="probs")
```

The codes work fine till this point, giving the probability of belonging to each group (1, 2, 3, 4) for each observation (region).

Probabilities:

```
Regions     groupadmit1       groupadmit2     groupadmit3    groupadmit4         
52            0.2484091        0.2494408       0.2505393      0.2516109
97            0.2483949        0.2494358       0.2505441      0.2516252
1300          0.2483253        0.2494112       0.2505676      0.251695
287           0.2483623        0.2494242       0.2505551      0.2516584
500,000         ....            .....            ....          ....
```

But, when I go to weight the sample (regions) according to their probability, it brings back the following error:

```
Warning message:
In wts[groupadmit == 1] <- probs[groupadmit == 1, 1]/probs[groupadmit ==  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What I am doing is weighting the regions according to their probability of belonging to each groupadmit proportional to the probability of belonging to groupadmit one in order to balance any chance for selection bias. It is very similar to inverse probability weighting. The codes are:

```
wts[groupadmit==1] <- probs[groupadmit==1,1]/probs[groupadmit==1,1]
wts[groupadmit==2] <- probs[groupadmit==2,1]/probs[groupadmit==2,2]
wts[groupadmit==3] <- probs[groupadmit==3,1]/probs[groupadmit==3,3]
wts[groupadmit==4] <- probs[groupadmit==4,1]/probs[groupadmit==4,4]
```

But, the above error comes up whenever I do the the analysis.
May someone please help me to understand why I get this error and how can I solve it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Salman, I added the data frame to the question as well. May you please check it now? Thanks

Comment: @Salman, Sorry I forgot to delete that line. That line is wrong. I will delete it from the question.

Comment: @Salman, to be honest I did not know what to put the t. So, I left it as it is. But, I know that I have to define the     wts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why R complains?**

```
Warning message:
In wts[groupadmit == 1] <- probs[groupadmit == 1, 1]/probs[groupadmit ==  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

it means that, the right handside of you `assign (<-)` is bigger than, what you have on the left handside which is  `wts[groupadmit==1]`

Therefore, i suggest you to do:

```
length(probs[groupadmit==1,1]/probs[groupadmit==1,1])
```

and then

```
length(wts[groupadmit==1])
```

Then i suppose, it shows the lefthand side is smaller.

Then simply run

```
wts[groupadmit==1] <- probs[groupadmit==1,1]/probs[groupadmit==1,1]
```

and finnally print

```
wts[groupadmit==1]
```

---

**Solution:**

A quick fix is to use `rbind` to build your `wts`:

```
wts<-rbind(probs[groupadmit==1,1]/probs[groupadmit==1,1], 
probs[groupadmit==2,1]/probs[groupadmit==2,2],
probs[groupadmit==3,1]/probs[groupadmit==3,3],
probs[groupadmit==4,1]/probs[groupadmit==4,4])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it does not work. Thanks any way.

Comment: @Eshmel please add the result of  the codes to your question. so, i can get more details from your question.

Comment: thanks, rbind works, but the problem is that as my data is so huge, my laptop stops working. I think I have to transfer it to data.table to make it work.

Comment: @Eshmel Please accept my answer if it was helpful. You should choose a small sample of data (about 100-200 rows). So, your laptop can handle it.

Comment: The code works, thanks. But I cannot choose a small sample, as I need all the data. I will sort it out, no worries. Thank you very much for your help.